# Numbers of years having rainy days in the range of 81–119% of long term average

Tags: r, dplyr

A day with precipitation >= 2.5 mm is called a rainy day. I could able to calculate monthwise rainy days using the following code

```
library(seas)
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)

data(mscdata)
dat.int <- (mksub(mscdata, id=1108447))

dat.int %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% # for easier viewing 
  mutate(yearmon = as.yearmon(dat.int$date, "%b %y")) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-date, -year, -yday, -t_max, -t_min, -t_mean) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -yearmon, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>% 
  group_by(yearmon, variable) %>% 
  summarise(rainy_days = sum(value > 2.5)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "variable", values_from = "rainy_days")
```

Then I have calculated the longterm average using the following code

```
dat.int %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% # for easier viewing 
  mutate(yearmon = as.yearmon(dat.int$date, "%b %y")) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-date, -year, -yday, -t_max, -t_min, -t_mean) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -yearmon, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>% 
  group_by(yearmon, variable) %>% 
  summarise(rainy_days = sum(value > 2.5)) %>% 
  mutate(year = year(yearmon)) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  summarize(value = as.integer(round(mean(rainy_days, na.rm = T)))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "variable", values_from = "value")
```

Now two thresholds should be calculated as: lower threshold = 0.81*long term average and upper threshold = 1.19*long term average. Then calculate the number of years having rainy days between these two thresholds. Now I want to calculate the number of years having rainy days in the range of 81–119% of long term average (between lower and upper threshold).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Based on OP's comments and wanting to summarize by total precip, rain and snow.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dat.int %>%
  mutate(month = month(ymd(date))) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(precip,rain,snow), funs(days = sum(. >= 2.5,na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(ends_with("days")), funs(yearly = sum(.))) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(-year), list(~ sum(. > mean(.) * 0.81 & . < mean(.) * 1.19))) %>%
  rename_all(list(~ gsub("days_yearly","in_range",.)))  summarize(years = n())
#  precip_in_range rain_in_range snow_in_range
#            <int>         <int>         <int>
#1              26            24             6
```

Comment: I want to apply for rain, snow, precip. I don't want yearly rainy days count. But the number of years having rainy days between these two thresholds. See my comment. So, the answer should be single number for rain, snow, precip each.

Comment: I have updated my question now. It should be number of years satisfying the conditions not number of days.

Comment: Can you do the option 2 for both rain and precip? I am having many stations. The output should give count of years satisfying the conditions.

Comment: I have updated my answer to do what I think you want.

Comment: Can you make it run for any column name, as in your code it is fixed for 3 variables. I am having 63 stations. For representation I have used default dataset. Can you make the code such that it can be run for n number of variables.

Comment: I believe this code is generalizable to any arbitrary column, defined in the first `sumarize_at` call by `vars(precip,rain,snow)`. You could use any of the `dplyr` helper functions to select columns, including `starts_with()` or `contains()`.